# According to Hindu philosophy, what are the flaws in Buddha's teachings?

Tags: philosophy, other-religions, buddhism

What are the flaws in Buddhism according to Hindu philosophers?

Did Buddha really reject the Vedas and Hinduism?

Comment: Buddhas teaching is not flaw. Understanding them has been flawed.

Comment: Well, there is [Buddhism.SE] for serious questions on Buddhism. We don't encourage cross religious questions here.

Comment: Buddhism stack exchange is a better place to ask your question. "What arguments did Hindu acharyas make against Buddhism?" would be a valid question for this site.

Comment: Related: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/35974/buddha-hinduism In fact @LazyLubber posted a long answer there :D

Comment: No.  Buddha did not reject Veda, but his followers misunderstood that aspect.  In fact Buddha reached the stage, which Rig Veda I.164.46 mentioned as SAT - सद.  Buddha's teachings are cryptic in nature, following the line of sages. As your question is being closed, I am not posting my answer. @Opi Chowdhury

Comment: This is asking for flaws in Buddhism according to Hindu scriptures or acharyas. Needs to be reopened.

Comment: @sv. We can also ask flaws in Jainism, Christianity, Islam and many other religions if framed this way.

Comment: @ I opine the same way. We should learn from the history. Bertrand Russel said that secluded civilizations perish, and Darwin stated that adaptation is key to survival.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Anything that is covered in Hindu scriptures especially about religion is on-topic. If you disagree, you can take it up on meta. Wanting to know how Jaina and Buddhist arguments were refuted in Hindu scriptures/commentaries is perfectly on-topic. Likewise, how the Hindu arguments were refuted maybe on topic for Buddhism SE. Christianity and Islam is on topic to the extent they are covered in Hindu scripture. Just because someone is going to get hurt we shouldn't disallow valid questions.

Comment: I already wrote a meta on it. It's already written and agreed that we don't allow cross religious questions. What other SE like Christianity allows is upto their meta. Our intention should be giving accurate information about anything be it Hinduism, Christianity. There is info about almost everything in Hindu scriptures from water cycle. That doesn't mean we allow all the questions about environment. Since this is Hinduism SE, we need not to talk about Buddhism, Christianity etc., There are other places to know better.

Comment: I think **sv.** is right about it, we are open to discuss anything related to Hinduism on this HiSE. This Q should be reopened.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Many texts argue against specific philosophies of their day. Should we also keep silent on Cārvāka and Ājīvika? There are many sects in Hinduism and these came from philosophical arguments in the texts. Buddhists and Jains (and some Liṅgāyats) also came from philosophical disputes. Even though they decided to split away from the Hinduism umbrella, we still have the same roots. So, I think questions about why/how these religions split should be on topic. Abrahamic religions shouldn't be

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Whether it is Abrahamic religion or a religion like Jainism or Buddhism, they will be treated the same. It is still a different religion than Hinduism. Buddhism and Jainism are not the same as Hinduism. They had roots but they are still  different religions. We are only Hinduism Stack Exchange. We have some limits. If we want to bring a relation, relation between Hinduism and Islam, Christianity can also be brought.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "They had roots but they are still different religions." The question is specifically about the transition "from roots to branches." Abrahamic faiths are rooted in Mesopotamia/Levant. Shinto in Japan. Zoroastrianism in Persia. Astika & nastika in India/Bharata. They have an obvious connection (cultural and philosophical) that the others don't. Also, if one can't ask a question about the transition between ancient Hinduism & Buddhism here, then where else will they be able to ask? Certainly not Buddhism.SE Rejecting a question can seem like we're calling it worthless

Answer (score 1):

> Did Buddha really reject the Vedas and Hinduism?

**Yes, he did.**

From the [Vishnu Purana](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp092.htm):

> In this manner, exclaiming to them, "Know!" (Budhyadwam), and they replying, "It is known" (Budhyate), these Daityas were induced by the arch-deceiver [Buddha] to deviate from their religious duties (and become Bauddhas), by his repeated arguments and variously urged persuasions, When they had abandoned their own faith, they persuaded others to do the same, and the heresy spread, and many deserted the practices enjoined by the Vedas and the laws.

The Vishnu Purana isn't the only scripture that says this since other Puranas and the Mahabharata also say the same thing.

If you want a non-Hindu source, then I believe even the original Buddhist works are opposed to the Vedas.

> What are the flaws in Buddhism according to Hindu philosophers?

The theories of Buddhism are refuted in Brahma Sutras [2.2.17 through 2.2.32.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/index.htm)

> [Summary:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Sutras#cite_note-63) The sutras 2.2.18 to 2.2.27 state and refute the 'persistence of subject and substance' theory, and sutras 2.2.28 to 2.2.32 state and refute the 'everything is void' theory of Buddhism.